# Slightly edited tensorflow official example doesn't run properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I'm working on word2vec via distributed tensorflow. For a compatible reason, just slightly edit official word2vec to a Model kinda coding arch.

Code Snippet as follows:

```
def build():
    self.global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    with tf.variable_scope("weights", partitioner=partitioner):

        self.embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="embeddings", shape=(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_size), initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0))
        self.nce_weights = tf.get_variable(name="nce_weights", shape=(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_size), initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(self.embedding_size)))
        self.bias = tf.get_variable(name="bias", shape=(self.vocab_size), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    self.embeded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs, partition_strategy='div')
    print("lables: ", self.labels)

    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.nce_loss(
            weights = self.nce_weights,
            biases = self.bias,
            labels = self.labels,
            inputs = self.embeded,
            num_sampled = self.num_sampled,
            num_classes = self.vocab_size,
            partition_strategy="div"
        )
    )

    self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)

    # evaluate
    normized = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
    normallized_embeddings = self.embeddings / normized
    valid_data = np.r_[1:5]
    self.valid_size = len(valid_data)
    evaluate_examples = tf.constant(valid_data)
    valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normallized_embeddings, evaluate_examples)
    self.similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, normallized_embeddings,  transpose_b=True)
```

The train method:

```
def train(args):
    loss, _, global_step, embs = session.run([self.loss, self.optimizer, self.global_step, self.embeddings])
    print(embs)
```

Training:

```
def main():
    model = Word2vec(args)
    model.build() # call the method above to build the graph
    tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        while num_step < upperboud:
             model.train(sess)
```

I print out the evaluation results during training, and found no changes all the time, but nce_weights are changing. And global_step and local_step are increasing. Not sure where is wrong, anyone can help point out ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share more details regarding how you are setting the global_step parameter?

Comment: Hi, Just added more details, global_step and local_step are increasing as expected, could you give me more suggestions ? Thanks @kvish